# Problems with emmeans if RE-adjustment and backtransformation from logit

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, contrasts, lsmeans, marginal-effect

In an experiment (4 sessions, 2 groups), subjects try to remember words.

**We want to test**

- H1: the overall (marginal) main effect of group
- H2: the specific interaction contrast of group and sesson1 _ 2

```r
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)
set.seed(123)

imgdat_final_shortterm[20:25, c("VP", "GROUP", "session", "items", "maxitems")]
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      VP GROUP     session items maxitems
#>   <dbl> <fct>     <fct>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     2 Imagery   3           6        8
#> 2     2 Imagery   3           6        8
#> 3     2 Imagery   4           6        8
#> 4     2 Imagery   4           6        8
#> 5     2 Imagery   4           7        8
#> 6     3 Rehearsal 4           5        8

fit <- glmer(cbind(items, maxitems - items) ~ session + GROUP + session:GROUP + 
                                  (1 | VP), 
                                data = imgdat_final_shortterm, family = binomial())
```

**H1: Marginal group effect**

- After regrid due to the RE-adjustment, the z- and p-values change (see following). Am I doing something wrong?

```r
emm_1_version2 <- emmeans(fit, specs = pairwise ~ GROUP, infer = c(T,T)
)
#> NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions

emm_1_version2[[2]]
#>  contrast            estimate    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL z.ratio p.value
#>  Imagery - Rehearsal  -0.0568 0.262 Inf     -0.57     0.456  -0.217  0.8281
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: session 
#> Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95

regrid(emm_1_version2[[2]], bias.adjust = TRUE, 
       sigma = as.numeric(attributes(lme4::VarCorr(fit)$VP)$stddev))
#>  contrast          odds.ratio    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL z.ratio p.value
#>  Imagery/Rehearsal       1.31 0.342 Inf     0.636      1.97   3.820  0.0001
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: session 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95
```

**H2: group x session1_2**

```r
emm_2 <- emmeans(fit, specs = ~ session * GROUP, adjust = "none")

emm_2_contrasts <- contrast(emm_2, interaction = c("revpairwise", "pairwise"),
              bias.adjust = TRUE, 
              sigma = as.numeric(attributes(lme4::VarCorr(fit_shortterm_assigned)$VP)$stddev)
              ,infer = c(T, T)
              , adjust = "none"
)
emm_2_contrasts
#>  session_revpairwise GROUP_pairwise      estimate    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
#>  2 - 1               Imagery - Rehearsal   0.3025 0.191 Inf   -0.0714     0.676
#>  3 - 1               Imagery - Rehearsal   0.1586 0.193 Inf   -0.2196     0.537
#>  3 - 2               Imagery - Rehearsal  -0.1438 0.188 Inf   -0.5120     0.224
#>  4 - 1               Imagery - Rehearsal   0.0578 0.196 Inf   -0.3254     0.441
#>  4 - 2               Imagery - Rehearsal  -0.2447 0.190 Inf   -0.6177     0.128
#>  4 - 3               Imagery - Rehearsal  -0.1008 0.192 Inf   -0.4770     0.275
#>  z.ratio p.value
#>    1.586  0.1128
#>    0.822  0.4110
#>   -0.766  0.4438
#>    0.296  0.7675
#>   -1.286  0.1986
#>   -0.525  0.5994
#> 
#> Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Is this correct? Again, tests and p-values change:

```r
regrid(emm_2_contrasts
       , transform = "response"
       , adjust = "none"
)
#>  session_revpairwise GROUP_pairwise    odds.ratio    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
#>  2/1                 Imagery/Rehearsal      1.353 0.258 Inf     0.847      1.86
#>  3/1                 Imagery/Rehearsal      1.172 0.226 Inf     0.729      1.62
#>  3/2                 Imagery/Rehearsal      0.866 0.163 Inf     0.547      1.18
#>  4/1                 Imagery/Rehearsal      1.060 0.207 Inf     0.654      1.47
#>  4/2                 Imagery/Rehearsal      0.783 0.149 Inf     0.491      1.08
#>  4/3                 Imagery/Rehearsal      0.904 0.174 Inf     0.564      1.24
#>  z.ratio p.value
#>    5.243  <.0001
#>    5.182  <.0001
#>    5.324  <.0001
#>    5.115  <.0001
#>    5.254  <.0001
#>    5.210  <.0001
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Regrid puts everything on the response scale, AND forgets the previous structure altogether. If instead you do `summary(..., type = "response")`, it does the tests on the logit scale and then back-transforms the results. Read the vignette on transformations and note what it says under "timing is everything."

Comment: Then, the null column in the results is 1.38 insted of 1.00 which makes CI's very difficult to interpret: 

I used: `summary(emm_2_contrasts , type = "response" , adjust = "none")`

Comment: Apparently because a RE-adjustment is involved. I came up with using regrid because of a similar case in https://github.com/easystats/modelbased/issues/57 (bottom). Do I need to take test- and p-values manually from the not regridded objects? And are the CI's still correct in the regridded one? They appear face-valid

Answer (score 1):

Following up on some comments... I had said

> Regrid puts everything on the response scale, AND forgets the previous structure altogether. If instead you do summary(..., type = "response"), it does the tests on the logit scale and then back-transforms the results. Read the vignette on transformations and note what it says under "timing is everything."

... and @Swarley responded

> Then, the null column in the results is 1.38 insted of 1.00 which makes CI's very difficult to interpret: I used: summary(emm_2_contrasts , type = "response" , adjust = "none")

*Yes, but...*

The bias adjustment requested in the OP is manifested in a *change to the inverse transformation* that is used. That change, among other things, causes

1. Increases in the estimated odds ratios
2. Increases in the confidence limits for them
3. A shift in the null value from 1.0 to 1.38 (in your case)

It does seem surprising to have a null value of 1.38; however, by (1) we have made all the estimates larger as well; we moved the estimates, and we moved the target. That 1.38 is the value that corresponds to a null of 0 *before* back-transformation (with the bias adjustment included). So if you want the P values to be the same as what you had on the link scale, the corresponding null on the response scale is 1.38.

But you can't have it both ways. If you want to test against a null of 1.0 on the response scale, then I guess the `regrid` strategy is what you need; but obviously, that gives you different P values.

#### What parameter do you want to make inferences about?

Another way to think about this is to ask whether you want to make inferences about the *mean*, or the *median*? The situation we have here is that, due to subject variations, the distribution of the odds ratios is log-normal. The log-normal distribution has two parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. It is a skewed distribution. The mean of that distribution is $e^{\mu + \frac12\sigma^2}$, and the median is $e^\mu$. The greater is $\sigma$, the bigger the discrepancy between the mean and the median.

In your case, your subject variations are enough to make the mean odds ratio 38% greater than the median, as demonstrated by the null value of 1.38. But note the median does not depend on $\sigma$. So if you want to think in terms of the *median* odds ratio, just remove the bias adjustment from all of this and you are making inferences about the median odds ratio, which on the link scale is assumed to be normal so that the median and the mean are the same. Doing that and using `type = "response"` will put the null median odds ratio back at 1.0, your confidence intervals will be for the median odds ratio, and everything will have a simpler interpretation in that context because tests on the link scale go hand-in-hand with the back-transformed versions of those.

Comment: Great explanations, I really appreciate that!

I wonder whether the approach using the median and not RE-adjusting at all does not have its problems. In that case, I would still use the un-adjusted confidence intervals which are still conditional on the random effects of this particular study. The median point estimate would be alright, but its CI not. 

I assume there is no simple way to calculate new z-values and p-values for the regrid object (e.g. based on a RE-adjusted SE)?

I would really like to see how this is done properly as this is a standard modeling case in psychology...

Comment: It's not conditional on the random effects, it is averaged over them. This is important, because the idea of random effects is that you can *expand* the scope of inference beyond the current study, in that the random subjects, etc. were sampled from the population of all subjects, etc. I don't see a problem with interpreting a CI of the mean of a normal population being interpreted as a CI for the median of some transformed version of that variable.

Comment: I am aware of what REs are, but I have difficulties to see why CIs of medians are not conditional on REs but averaged over them even if I did not do any RE-adjustment.

Comment: Well, in a simple design with 10 random subjects and 4 observations per subject, the variance of each treatment mean (on the link scale) is Var(subj)/10 + Var(error)/40. I'd call that the variance of an average with two random components. And our CI for the mean (which is equal to the median) on the link scale is the estimate +/- (about 2) * sqrt(above). And the median gets transformed directly when we transform to the response scale; so when we transform the CI endpoints to the response scale, we obtain a CI for the median. Maybe you can discuss this with a colleague?